# XSLT output is not correct

Tags: xslt

I am trying to figure out what is wrong with my xsl file. Here is my sample xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<session xmlns="http://winscp.net/schema/session/1.0" name="user@host" start="2015-12-30T14:55:40.156Z">
  <ls>
    <destination value="/test/folder" />
    <files>
      <file>
        <filename value="folder1" />
        <type value="d" />
        <modification value="2015-03-04T21:09:25.000Z" />
        <permissions value="rwxrw-rw-" />
      </file>
      <file>
        <filename value="folder2" />
        <type value="d" />
        <modification value="2015-03-04T21:08:47.000Z" />
        <permissions value="rwxrw-rw-" />
      </file>
      <file>
        <filename value="folder3" />
        <type value="d" />
        <modification value="2015-03-04T21:08:57.000Z" />
        <permissions value="rwxrw-rw-" />
      </file>
      <file>
        <filename value="folder4" />
        <type value="d" />
        <modification value="2015-03-04T21:09:14.000Z" />
        <permissions value="rwxrw-rw-" />
      </file>
      <file>
        <filename value="file1.txt" />
        <type value="-" />
        <size value="113" />
        <modification value="2015-12-30T14:55:07.000Z" />
        <permissions value="rw-rw-rw-" />
      </file>
    </files>
    <result success="true" />
  </ls>
</session>
```

This is my xsl file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>filename,filedatetime,filetype</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="file"/> 
    <xsl:text>-eof-</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="file">
    <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="filename/@value" />
    <xsl:text>","</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="modification/@value" />
    <xsl:text>","</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="type/@value" />
    <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output that I am getting is:

```
filename,filedatetime,filetype
-eof-
```

I cannot seem to figure out how to get the values of "filename", "modification" and "type" elements. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `<xsl:apply-templates select="file"/>` will only match immediate children of the root node of type `file` and there aren't any of those.

If you want all `file` children at any depth you could use `<xsl:apply-templates select="//file"/>` instead.

The XML has a default namespace, so the elements in your XSL won't match unless their namespaces match too.

The following seems to work (note the definition and use of the `xx` namespace):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:xx="http://winscp.net/schema/session/1.0">

    <xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:text>filename,filedatetime,filetype</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//xx:file" />
        <xsl:text>-eof-</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="xx:file">
        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="xx:filename/@value" />
        <xsl:text>","</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="xx:modification/@value" />
        <xsl:text>","</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="xx:type/@value" />
        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I tried adding "session/ls/files/file" to both, apply-template as well as template select. It still does not provide the output I am looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation as well as the correct code. Your solution worked perfectly for me! Appreciate your time. :)